# Slack unfurling not working on external workspaces?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I followed these directions ([link](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/link-unfurling#slack_app_unfurling)) to handle unfurling of links to my product, so that anytime that users post our links, we'd display additional rich information.

It works when I test it on my own Slack workspace, but I can't get it to work on other workspaces. I've tried reinstalling the app on the other workspaces since adding new permissions, and adding the bot to specific channels where I'm testing, and no luck.

Is there any additional configuration that's required to make unfurling work on 3rd party Slack workspaces? This is for a Slack app that's not on the Slack App Directory, and being privately distributed (not officially reviewed by Slack yet)

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing in the other workspaces? Any errors or simply a message with a url that doesn't unfurl?

Comment: External workspace: no error, it was just showing the default OpenGraph link preview, and never hitting my server with the /events notification

Comment: Solution: ended up creating new Oauth authentication links that included the link:read and link:write permissions, and now everything works fine. Before, I was relying on the ShareableURL in the Manage Distribution tab of the SlackAPI website, with the false assumption that this link would cover the permissions I requested in the "Oauth & Permisions" tab

Comment: @sandra Sorry to hop on your question, in my case it's very similar but I get `cannot_find_channel` exception thrown by Bolt JS. _(only on 3rd party workspaces)_

Comment: @Petruza So you're getting `cannot_find_channel` as a response to `chat.unfurl`?

Comment: @sandra, yes thanks, you already answered this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69317467/calling-link-unfurl-endpoint-on-slack-api-woks-on-own-workspace-errors-cannot?noredirect=1#comment122574920_69317467