# Calling link unfurl endpoint on Slack API woks on own workspace, errors `cannot_find_channel` on 3rd party workspaces

Tags: slack, slack-api, bolt.js

I’m using the Bolt JS library to unfurl links.
I’m sending the `event.channel` as the unfurl channel option.
This works for the workspace I developed the app from.
Then I installed the app in a different workspace and tested unfurling. My app server gets called with the correct URLs and everything, but when I call the unfurl endpoint I get the error `cannot_find_channel`
Any ideas? do I have to do anything else than add to slack from that external workspace for it to work properly?

Comment: And you've made sure that the channel id exists and that the token you're using belongs to the new workspace?

Comment: I just pass the event.channel so it should exist, I assume.
But you're right, I was using the app bot token always. So the event doesn't provide you with that specific workspace bot token but you have to store it yourself when they request to install the app on that workspace, right?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't be secure if Slack provided the token with the event.